# Initialize char arrays from string literal

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11

I have a struct with char array inside it, however I can't find a decent way to initialize it if string becomes longer.

```
struct T
{
    char id[4];
};

T t{ 'a','b', 'c','d'}; // case 1: OK

T t{"abcd"};   // case 2: ERROR, "abcd" size is 5, too long for id
```

I get below error:

```
   error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]
     T t{"abcd"};
```

The reason is that string literal "abcd" contains null terminator, so the size is 5.

This syntax is allowed [C99 string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), how can I work around in C++11?

Comment: Perhaps a workaround is to take a c string in a constructor and copy 4 chars from it but be careful in case it is smaller.

Comment: @NeilKirk sorry forgot to mention that type T is third party lib, I can't change that.

Comment: Sounds like not a very high-quality 3rd-party library, or perhaps you just missed something in the API. If it's really that bad, why not derive a class of your own from it so that you can add whatever "nice" stuff you want to the interface?

Comment: how does T constructor declarations looks like in the header?

Comment: @DavidK 3rdparty C lib is very common.

Comment: Use a function to create it from a c string.

Comment: @NeilKirk do you mean `T t{func("abcd)};` ?

Comment: Isn't `T t{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};` a good enough work around?

Comment: @RSahu it's OK when string is short, I have some of them are defined with `char[32]`

Comment: I have a feeling that is your best option. Good luck with finding something better.

Comment: Why don't you use std:string since you are using c++? They are designed to handle different lengths correctly

Comment: The main problem is that you are not taking in reference the '\0' char from the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're out of luck. If you can't change `T` then there is no workaround unless you give up on direct initialization. You'll have to use `T t{'a', 'b', 'c'};` etc.  This is because `T` is an aggregate, so the only form of initialization is to pass actual initializers for each element.

Of course you can write a function, e.g.:

```
T t = T_from_literal("abcdefgh...");
```

where that function uses `std::copy` or similar to copy the characters into a `T t;` and returns by value, taking advantage of copy elision.

Answer (score 0):

You may mind the `'\0'` char in the end of the string when initializing, so you always have to take one more char to make it work:

```
struct T
{
    char id[5];
};
```

See this [example](http://cpp.sh/7thj)